# Is there any way in which I can clean up my code by assigning a linq query to a single variable of type string?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

I made a login system for a project that I have been working on and while it works, it doesn't seem to look like the most efficient way I could do it. This is a WPF/C# project linked to an SQLite database that uses LINQ for queries. Ideally, I would like the query to spit out a single variable of type string so that I can manipulate it and compare it with what the user enter.

```
List<Engineer> engineers;
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string username = UsernameField.Text;
            string password = PasswordField.Password.ToString();
            string hashedPasswordString = "";
            string saltString = "";

            //establishes connection
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.engineerDatabasePath))
            {

                engineers = conn.Table<Engineer>().ToList();
                //Queries for a list containing the respective hashed passwords. This will only contain one password since the emails are unique
                var hashedpasswordlist = from c in engineers
                                     where c.Email == username
                                     select c.Password;

                //Take the password in the list and assign it to a string variable that can be compared
                foreach (var item in hashedpasswordlist)
                {
                    hashedPasswordString = item;
                }

                //Queries for a list containing the respective salts. This will only contain one salt since the emails are unique
                var saltlist = from c in engineers
                               where c.Email == username
                               select c.Salt;

                //Take the salt in the list and assign it to a variable to the password input, creating a hash value that is to be assigned
                foreach (var item in saltlist)
                {
                    saltString = item;
                }

                //Confirmation that the implementation works as it should
                if (GenerateSHA256Hash(password, saltString) == hashedPasswordString) 
                {
                    MessageBoxResult deleteConfirmation = MessageBox.Show("IT WORKS!", "Grats", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
                }

            }
            //Allows you to log in regardless of whether your login details are correct. This is the case for testing purposes.
            MainWindow MainWindow = new MainWindow();
            MainWindow.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
```

**Here is the GenerateSHA256Hash method and the ByteArrayToHexString method**

```
 public string GenerateSHA256Hash(string input, string salt)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input + salt);
            System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed sha256hashtring = new System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hash = sha256hashtring.ComputeHash(bytes);

            return ByteArrayToHexString(hash);
        }

        public static string ByteArrayToHexString(byte[] ba)
        {
            StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);

            foreach (byte b in ba)
            {
                hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
            }

            return hex.ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took @D Stanley 's method and combined it with @iSR5 's lack of variables to create the following:

```
using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.engineerDatabasePath))
                {

                    var saltedPassword = (from c in conn.Table<Engineer>()
                                          where c.Email == UsernameField.Text
                                          select new { c.Password, c.Salt }).SingleOrDefault();

                    if (saltedPassword != null)
                    {
                        if (GenerateSHA256Hash(PasswordField.Password.ToString(), saltedPassword.Salt) == saltedPassword.Password)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Correct credentials, click ok to continue", "Access Granted", MessageBoxButton.OK);
                            MainWindow MainWindow = new MainWindow();
                            MainWindow.Show();
                            this.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect credentials", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
                    }

                }
```

It seems that when an email is not found, saltedPassword will end up being null so I also wrote an if statement in order to make sure that the program doesn't crash when that happens. I was thinking of venturing into lambda expressions and throwing null exceptions but I am still quite new to programming and lack knowledge in those areas.

Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to retrieve the *actual* password and compare it to what the user entered, you shouldn't do that.  Password should not be stored in a retrievable format in the database for security reasons, so hashing the entered password and comparing it to the hash in the database is much more secure (and not much less efficient) than comparing directly.

That said, you *could* retrieve both the salt and the hash in one step, and use `SingleOrDefault()` since you only expect one item:

```
//Queries for a list containing the respective hashed passwords. This will only contain one password since the emails are unique
var saltedPassword = (from c in conn.Table<Engineer>()
                     where c.Email == username
                     select new {c.Password, c.Salt}).SingleOrDefault();

//TODO: Add handling for when password is not found (saltedPassword is null)

hashedPasswordString = saltedPassword.Password;
saltString = saltedPassword.Salt;
```

Comment: Also `engineers` should just be `conn.Table<Engineer>()` without the `ToList` as this avoids loading the complete table just to get one entry.

Comment: @ckuri Good catch-  I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

You're querying `Engineer` table, so it's obvious that the return would be `Engineer` object, and since you're querying for the same object, you need to query the table, get the results as `Engineer` object, then navigate through its properties.

There is no need to query multiple times, just once is enough.

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Basic null handling 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(UsernameField.Text)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(UsernameField.Text)); }

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(PasswordField.Password?.ToString())) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(UsernameField.Text)); }

    //establishes connection
    using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.engineerDatabasePath))
    {
        // get the Engineer object
        var engineer = conn.Table<Engineer>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Email.Equals(UsernameField.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

        // generate the password
        var password = GenerateSHA256Hash(PasswordField.Password.ToString(), engineer.Salt); 

        //Confirmation that the implementation works as it should
        if (engineer.Password.Equals(password))
        {
            MessageBoxResult deleteConfirmation = MessageBox.Show("IT WORKS!", "Grats", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }

    }
    //Allows you to log in regardless of whether your login details are correct. This is the case for testing purposes.
    MainWindow MainWindow = new MainWindow();
    MainWindow.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your first line and build on it

```
engineers = conn.Table<Engineer>().ToList();



var engineer = conn.Table<Engineer>().First(x=>x.Email.Equals(username)); 

var password = conn.Table<Engineer>().First(x=>x.Email.Equals(username)).Password;

var saltString = engineer.Salt

var pw = engineer.Password
```